# Nuxt.js vuetify.css not found

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm getting a compilation error when trying to run nuxt with vuetify. It says that `vuetify.css` was not found with the dependency absolute path. I checked in `buildDir/App.js` and `vuetify.css` is the only dependency  to reference a fullpath. Is there a reason to that ?
What do I miss ?

`yarn dev`

```
This dependency was not found:                                               friendly-errors 10:34:11
                                                                             friendly-errors 10:34:11
* .\full\path\to\myproject\src\node_modules\vuetify\dist\vuetify.css in ./myproject/prod/server/nuxt/App.js
                                                                             friendly-errors 10:34:11
To install it, you can run: npm install --save .\full\path\to\myproject\src\node_modules\vuetify\dist\vuetify.css
```

buildDir/App.js

```
...
import '..\\..\\..\\src\\assets\\main.css'

import '..\\..\\..\\src\\assets\\variables.scss'

import '.\\full\\path\\to\\myproject\\src\\node_modules\\vuetify\\dist\\vuetify.css'

import _6f6c098b from '..\\..\\..\\src\\layouts\\default.vue'
...
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.9.2",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^4.1.0",
    "firebase": "^7.10.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.8.7",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "core-js": "3",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "vue-jest": "^4.0.0-0"
  }
```

nuxt.config.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' })

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  server: {
    host: process.env.HOST_NAME,
    port: process.env.HOST_PORT
  },
  env: process.env,
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.npm_package_name,
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900' },
    ]
  },
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  css: [
    '@/assets/main.css',
    '@/assets/variables.scss'
  ],
  plugins: [],
  buildModules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { }],
    ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { path: '../', filename: '.env' }]
  ],
  modules: [],
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    optionsPath: "./vuetify.options.js",
  },
  buildDir: "../prod/server/nuxt",
  build: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        '_': 'lodash'
      })
    ],
    extractCSS: true,
    extend (config, ctx) {},
    babel: {
      presets({ isServer }) {
        return [
          [
            require.resolve('@nuxt/babel-preset-app'),
            {
              buildTarget: isServer ? 'server' : 'client',
              corejs: { version: 3 }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a new project?
Sorry just my curiosity because you are using the old vuetify version.

Comment: Yes, it's a new project. The `package.json` was referring to version 1.0.0, but i am using the version 1.11.0. I updated the post.

Comment: can you try change the code:   buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv', { path: '../', filename: '.env' }
  ],

Comment: another thing, here in my nuxt,config.js i have in my build session this property:   build: { transpile: ['vuetify/lib'] }

Comment: Tried both independently and together, but still getting the same error

Comment: can you try change your CORE-JS to version "core-js": "^2.6.10", and check again?

Comment: Now I get this error https://gist.github.com/belgacea/85c1fadfd3221cf7f3242c4a9026dba8

Comment: have the same error, notice - built & run works ok

Comment: Made issue to repo with some descriptions https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/347